# Erro no código arquivo.exe parou de funcionar - Linguagem C

Tags: c

Eu sou um programador iniciante e estive passando um bom tempo para programar um jogo da velha. Eu fiz ele funcionar com o bot jogando aleatoriamente, então, para criar mais um nível de dificuldade, eu comecei a criar uma I.A. bem básica através de uma cadeia de if e else.

O problema está justamente nessa cadeia.

A principio, eu procurei na internet e após umas pesquisas, cheguei a conclusão que eu escrevi errado alguma parte dessa cadeia. Eu procurei, procurei, mas não achei, então vim pedir vossa ajuda.

```
void jogadaPChard(void)
{
    int coluna, linha;

    if(_tabuleiro[0][0]+_tabuleiro[0][1]==10)
        {linha=0;coluna=2;}
    else
        if(_tabuleiro[0][1]+_tabuleiro[0][2]==10)
            {linha=0;coluna=0;}
        else
            if(_tabuleiro[0][0]+_tabuleiro[0][2]==10)
                {linha=0;coluna=1;}
            else
                if(_tabuleiro[1][0]+_tabuleiro[1][1]==10)
                    {linha=1;coluna=2;}
                else
                    if(_tabuleiro[1][1]+_tabuleiro[1][2]==10)
                        {linha=1;coluna=0;}
                    else
                        if(_tabuleiro[1][0]+_tabuleiro[1][2]==10)
                            {linha=1;coluna=1;}
                        else
                            if(_tabuleiro[2][0]+_tabuleiro[2][1]==10)
                                {linha=2;coluna=2;}
                            else
                                if(_tabuleiro[2][1]+_tabuleiro[2][2]==10)
                                    {linha=2;coluna=0;}
                                else
                                    if(_tabuleiro[2][0]+_tabuleiro[2][2]==10)
                                        {linha=2;coluna=1;}
                                    else
                                        if(_tabuleiro[0][0]+_tabuleiro[1][0]==10)
                                            {linha=0;coluna=2;}
                                        else
                                            if(_tabuleiro[1][0]+_tabuleiro[2][0]==10)
                                                {linha=0;coluna=0;}
                                            else
                                                if(_tabuleiro[0][0]+_tabuleiro[2][0]==10)
                                                    {linha=1;coluna=2;}
                                                else
                                                    if(_tabuleiro[0][1]+_tabuleiro[1][1]==10)
                                                        {linha=2;coluna=1;}
                                                    else
                                                        if(_tabuleiro[1][1]+_tabuleiro[2][1]==10)
                                                            {linha=0;coluna=1;}
                                                        else
                                                            if(_tabuleiro[0][1]+_tabuleiro[2][1]==10)
                                                                {linha=1;coluna=1;}
                                                            else
                                                                if(_tabuleiro[0][2]+_tabuleiro[1][2]==10)
                                                                    {linha=2;coluna=2;}
                                                                else
                                                                    if(_tabuleiro[1][2]+_tabuleiro[2][2]==10)
                                                                        {linha=0;coluna=2;}
                                                                    else
                                                                        if(_tabuleiro[0][2]+_tabuleiro[2][2]==10)
                                                                            {linha=1;coluna=2;}
                                                                        else
                                                                            if(_tabuleiro[0][0]+_tabuleiro[1][1]==10)
                                                                                {linha=2;coluna=2;}
                                                                            else
                                                                                if(_tabuleiro[1][1]+_tabuleiro[2][2]==10)
                                                                                    {linha=0;coluna=0;}
                                                                                else
                                                                                    if(_tabuleiro[0][0]+_tabuleiro[2][2]==10)
                                                                                        {linha=1;coluna=1;}
                                                                                    else
                                                                                        if(_tabuleiro[0][2]+_tabuleiro[1][1]==10)
                                                                                            {linha=2;coluna=0;}
                                                                                        else
                                                                                            if(_tabuleiro[1][1]+_tabuleiro[2][0]==10)
                                                                                                {linha=0;coluna=2;}
                                                                                            else
                                                                                                if(_tabuleiro[2][0]+_tabuleiro[0][2]==10)
                                                                                                    {linha=1;coluna=1;}
                                                                                                else
                                                                                                    jogadaPC();

    if(_tabuleiro[linha][coluna]==0)
        _tabuleiro[linha][coluna] = 250;
    else
        jogadaPC();
}
```

Apenas quero dizer que a função jogadaPC(); é a mais simples e está funcionando sem erros.

Comment: Identificou bem o local do problema. Não é para fazer isto. Isto é confuso demais. Se fizer uma laço e reduzir isto para poucas linhas, aí fica mais fácil detectar outros problemas. Pelo menos poderia tirar esse monte de  `else` desnecessários.

Comment: mas como eu faria esse laço? eu vou tirar todos os else e verei o q acontece

Comment: Aí o problema é mais embaixo então .Acho que você pegou um problema complicado demais para o que sabe fazer. Seria interessante começar com algo mais simples, dar uma passo de cada vez, pular etapas não vai acelerar seu aprendizado, pelo contrário, deixará lacunas difíceis de arrumar depois.

Comment: obrigado cara, retirar todos os else solucionou o problema. Mas pq todos aqueles else estavam prejudicando o funcionamento do programa?

Comment: Porque eles impediam a execução normal. Mas eu ainda tenho medo do que sobrou.

Comment: Funcionou provavelmente porque era necessário passar por todos os ifs e executar cada um que fosse verdadeiro. Como está, quando um dos ifs é executado ele não prossegue pelos demais ifs que estão encadeados pelos elses (a sequência de ifs é quebrada). Veja que o JogadaPC() só é executado se todos os ifs forem falsos, acho que não foi isso que você planejou..Tirando os elses, JogadaPC() sempre será executado após cada if ter sido verificado e independente de darem verdadeiro ou falso. Não é isso?

Comment: na vdd, minha intenção era justamente só executar o jogadaPC() caso todos os if's darem falso, mas dps dos comentários do bigown, eu percebi que eles eram inúteis, pq o programa não precisava deles para criar a condição que eu queria, obrigado, mesmo assim, por comentar